# Induction proof for continued fractions

Tags: proof-writing, induction, continued-fractions

Recently while preparing for a maths test, I got this question in a book:

**Let $a(n) =  3 + \cfrac{1}{3+\cfrac{1}{3+\cfrac{1}{3+\cdots }}}$ till $n$ terms.**

**Prove that $a(n) \cdot a(n-1)=3a(n-1)+1$ for $n \geqslant 2$.**

I just don't know how to start proving that the equation is valid for $(k+1)$th term also.

Any help would be surely appreciated. :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

$a(n) =  3 + \dfrac{1}{\color{red}{3+\dfrac{1}{3+\dfrac{1}{3+\cdots }}}} = 3 + \dfrac{1}{\color{red}{a(n-1)}} $